# Which pullbacks preserve the sheaf of differentials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of $S$-schemes. Assume that the canonical morphism $\alpha : f^* \Omega^1_{Y/S} \to \Omega^1_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism. What can we say about $f$? Is $f$ formally étale? Of course we may assume that $S$ is affine.

Background: It is known that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism when $f$ is formally étale (EGA IV, 17.2.4). One can show that $\alpha$ is an epimorphism if and only if $f$ is formally unramified (EGA IV, 17.2.2), and $\alpha$ is a monomorphism if  $f$ is smooth (EGA IV, 17.2.3). So my question is if the converse also holds.

Comment: I don't know know if this is what you're looking for, but the converse holds ($f$ must be etale) when $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over $S$ and we assume $f$ is locally of finite presentation.

Comment: Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, let $Y$ be the spectrum of $k[t]$ and let $X$ be the spectrum of $k[t]/(t^p)$. The closed immersion of $X$ in $Y$ is a counterexample to the converse.

Comment: Alex and Cantlog, thank you for these answers. Why don't you post them as answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Mr. Brandenburg's request:

This comes from Lei Fu's *Etale Cohomology* (it's proposition 2.5.3)

> **Theorem:** Let $S$ be a scheme, $X$ and $Y$ two $S$-schemes, and $f:X\to Y$ a morphism of $S$-schemes locally of finite presentation. If $f$ is etale, then the canonical map $f^\ast\Omega_{Y/S}\to\Omega_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism. The converse holds if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over $S$.

Comment: And none of the hypothesis on $X, Y$ can't be removed. We already saw an example with $X$ non-smooth. If we take $Y$ be a nodal curve and $X$ its normalization, then we get another (counter)example.